# Firefox. Create an extension to search on page with regexp

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'd like to create an extension that allows the searching on a webpage using regular expressions.
In fact i wanna override the find toolbar behavior so that it finds the text on a page with regexp.

I'm a beginner in the extensions development. So i don't know how to get access to the FindBar and especially to the Find text box.

i found that there is a file findbar.xml that contains the "_find" method. it performs the main functionality. but how can i change it?

Comment: Addons already exist with this functionality; maybe you could find a thing or two in their documentation: http://superuser.com/questions/208652/how-do-i-search-a-page-using-a-regular-expression-in-firefox

Comment: thanks. these addons are good. but there is a lot of files and xul-js code. so i can't completely understand what i can copy into my project. i can't understand the principle of redefining existing components of the browser

Comment: Copy & paste is a TERRIBLE way to learn. Why don't you try to *modify* an existing addon. (e.g: remove features until it does just a single basic thing, then change that to be more like what you want). There's no getting around the fact that you'll need to learn the basics of XUL development, as well as the use of privileged JavaScript APIs on the Mozilla platform.

Comment: I've just installed from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regex-find/ and like it so far. When I checked the GitHub project page, I realised I'd seen the Master of Puppets cover earlier while doing my research. I'd be confident that now (two and a half years later) you are in a great place to answer this question, yourself. Great work!

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks. Now I have the answer.